# How can I trigger a segue from UIBarButtonItem using storyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

My UIViewController subclass has a valid "- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender" defined, the segue is listed as a connection from the UIBarButtonItem to the destination controller, but prepareForSegue is never triggered. The button animates that a tap has occurred though.

There is also no additional action connected to the button that I have defined. Is there a special way to handle UIBarButtonItems?

Comment: Is the segue working properly, it's just that prepareForSegue is not triggered? Or can you just see that the button animates the tap, but you're not segued to the destination vc?

Comment: Apologies for wasting everyone's time. It was a gesture recogniser gobbling all the touches (even though the button was animating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action for the button, try calling this method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueName" sender:self];
```

This should trigger the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: I definitely understood that method of triggering the segue. What is the purpose of the connection then?

Comment: You're telling the system that there is a connection between the two. In code, you are not detailing what the destination is. The system looks for the provided connection name (segue name), and thereby finds the destination viewcontroller

Comment: You should make the segue from the vc itself, not from the button. The button needs an action anyway, or nothing will happen. The segue is not am action in and of itself. It is just a path.

Comment: I thought I understood all that... however, if I add a button to the scene and add a triggered segue from it to the vc, prepareForSegue is called without a button action. That is what I'm trying to understand. The difference between a regular button and UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Ok, there must be something else wrong then. I just tried both scenarios: having two viewcontrollers, adding a uibutton with a triggered segue, and also replacing the button with a uibarbuttonitem with a triggered segue. In both cases, prepareForSegue is triggered, and the segue works as expected. Both cases use a uinavigationcontroller, of course, which is mandatory for using push segues...

Comment: I'm not even getting the wired action to trigger atm. I'm testing on an iOS6 device right now.  I'm gonna try an iOS7 device and a new project. I've rewired the connections multiple times. If you have it all working, then I imagine I've done something incorrectly or it's an issue with the latest sdk and iOS6.

Comment: The demo I just setup worked as I originally expected and as you have stated. I'm not sure what is wrong with my current project. Thanks for the patience @Handsomeguy.